# Executing shell script from another shell script and passing keyword as argument

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have written a script file to check the free space on the disk. If the used space is higher than a threshold, I wish to restart an application on that server.

Below is the code I have written.

```
CURRENT=$(df / | grep / | awk '{ print $5}' | sed 's/%//g')
THRESHOLD=60
echo $CURRENT
if [ "$CURRENT" -gt "$THRESHOLD" ] ; then
echo "inside"
    sudo ./script2.sh stop
    sudo ./script2.sh start
fi
```

The `script2.sh` takes `start|stop` as argument.

The commands `sudo ./script2.sh stop` and `sudo ./script2.sh start` when executed directly from the terminal executes correctly.

The first command `sudo ./script2.sh stop` doesn't execute. I am guessing because `stop` is a keyword in linux and hence causing the issue.

The second command `sudo ./script2.sh start` executes (but gives 'Address already in use' error as the first script did not execute).

I know I might have to change the argument value from start to something else, but is there any solution to pass `stop` as an argument to the script?

Comment: I have tried placing it in inverted comma's, still same issue

Comment: "I am guessing because stop is a keyword in linux and hence causing the issue." -  Why do you think this is true. ? Test run `sh -x ./script2.sh stop`   and check what is wrong

Comment: What is a "keyword"?  There is nothing special about the argument "stop".

Comment: Don't pipe grep to awk to sed.  If you're going to do this, just do `df / | awk 'NR==2{print $5}' FS=' *|%'`

Comment: The issue is not in that line @WilliamPursell. The issue is when running `sudo ./script2.sh stop`

Comment: @swithencolaco Indeed, piping grep to awk to sed is not the root problem you are describing.  It is bad practice, however.

Comment: This smells like an XY problem. The problem is not in this code. What does script2 do when it gets the "stop" parameter?

Comment: @glennjackman stop parameter kills the process

Answer (score 1):

Try with instantiating a shell with root privileges and running the script within it:

```
#!/bin/bash
CURRENT=$(df / | grep / | awk '{ print $5}' | sed 's/%//g')
THRESHOLD=60
echo $CURRENT
if [ "$CURRENT" -gt "$THRESHOLD" ] ; then
echo "inside"
    sudo bash -c  './script2.sh stop'
    sudo bash -c  './script2.sh start'
fi
```

This could also be done in one line..  Something like `sudo bash -c  './script2.sh stop; ./script2.sh start'.`

Also note that you did not specify shell on the first line, use shebang like #!/bin/bash or whatever shell you are using

Comment: I made the modifications to the code and ran it. I didn't get any error but the first command didn't execute.